# My php code not getting add correct

Tags: php

I making one counter, I am using PHP and almost everything was going fine but i found one small bug in it.

My first two step on counter is going fine that is `$bid` and `$stax`.

My last result `$pay` should be : `8138 + 814 + 448 = 9400` but it is giving me `$9,399`

**My Output is:**

```
Value $8,138 bid $814 tax $448 You Pay $9,399
Value $8,952 bid $895 tax $492 You Pay $10,339
Value $9,847 bid $985 tax $542 You Pay $11,373
```

Here is my php

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$v = 8138;  // value : 8138
do {
    $i++;
    $bid  = $v / 10;      // output : $814
    $ftax = $v + $bid;
    $stax = $ftax / 20;  // output : tax $448
    $pay  = $v + $bid + $stax;   // 8138 + 814 + 448 = 9400
    echo "Value $" . number_format($v) . " bid $" . number_format($bid) . " tax $" . number_format($stax) . " You Pay $" . number_format($pay) . "<br />";
    $v = $v * 1.1;
} while ($i <= 2);
?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you are losing some decimals along the way there....

Comment: ahhhh i will try with my calculator

Comment: Yeah $bid has decimal places on it and $stax. You need to round them up or down if you don't want to use decimals.

Comment: thanks i will round them first before checking my pay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your echo line to not drop decimals:

```
echo "Value $" . $v . " bid $" . $bid . " tax $" . $stax . " You Pay $" . $pay . "<br />";
```

> Value $8138 bid $813.8 tax $447.59 You Pay $9399.39
> Value $8951.8 bid $895.18 tax $492.349 You Pay $10339.329
> Value $9846.98 bid $984.698 tax $541.5839 You Pay $11373.2619

So 8138 + 813.8 + 447.59 = 9399.39, which rounds down to 9399.

On the other hand, if you round immediately, 813.8 rounds up to 814 and 447.59 rounds up to 448, but you've just added 0.61 to your calculation before even starting, which obviously results in a higher number (9400).

This is why math and science teachers tell you not to round until the very end, since each time you do it, your answer gets less accurate.

Comment: Thanks Brendan Long for the help :) i will have to round them up

Comment: @DeepakKumar Don't round them first!! The 9399 answer is **correct**! This answer is just explaining why it's correct. You don't need to change anything (except maybe displaying decimals if you think your users will be confused).

Comment: I want it 9400 so have to round them up. as per my need it has to be 9400

Answer (score 3):

if you dont want to use decimals, round off all division calculations by using `round()`. Also, multiplications with decimals. See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/XNStPbeV)

```
$i = 0;
$v = 8138;  // value : 8138
 do {
$i++;
$bid  = round($v / 10);      // output : $814
$ftax = $v + $bid;
$stax = round($ftax / 20);  // output : tax $448
$pay  = $v + $bid + $stax;   // 8138 + 814 + 448 = 9400
echo "Value $" . number_format($v) . " bid $" . number_format($bid) . " tax $" .      number_format($stax) . " You Pay $" . number_format($pay) . "<br />";
$v = round($v * 1.1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lack of casting/decimals be ye problem matey. har har har